# How to execute the html template

Tags: html, go, authorization

In this code, I am trying to execute the `tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(res, "about.html", d)` that is present in the `showAbout()` function.

In the `handler.go` file, I have two functions. The first one is `showAbout()` and the second is `about()`. `about()` function check the authorization and after successful authorization, it goes to the `showAbout()` function in which it has if-statement.

If the about field is empty in the database then it should execute the `aboutform.html`, take the data and insert it in the database.

If the data is inserted successfully then show the message and go back to `about.html` to show the data there.

Only `about.html` is not executing. Although the success message is given.

**about.html**

```
<section>
   <h1>About</h1>
   <hr>
   <p>{{.Aboutdata}}</p>
</section>
```

**aboutform.html**

```
<form action="/about" method="POST">
    <section>
        <label>Content</label>
        <textarea name="content"></textarea>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </div>
    </section>
</form>
```

**db.go**

```
func Insertdata(key, value string) bool {
    collection := Connect.Database("webApp3").Collection("data")
    filter := bson.M{"email": Account.Email, "password": Account.Password}
    update := bson.M{
        "$set": bson.M{
            key: value,
        },
    }
    _, err := collection.UpdateOne(context.TODO(), filter, update)
    return err == nil
}
```

**handler.go**

```
func showAbout(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    d := struct{ Aboutdata string }{Aboutdata: database.Account.About}
    if d.Aboutdata == "" {
        tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(res, "aboutform.html", nil)
        content := req.FormValue("content")
        inserted := database.Insertdata("about", content)
        if inserted == true {
            fmt.Println("About is successfully inserted")
            tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(res, "about.html", d)   // It is not executing the about.html file
        } else {
            fmt.Println("About is not inserted")
        }
    } else {
        tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(res, "about.html", d)    // Although this same file is executing here.
    }
}

func about(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    session, _ := store.Get(req, "session-name")
    var authenticated interface{} = session.Values["authenticated"]
    if authenticated != nil {
        isAuthenticated := session.Values["authenticated"].(bool)
        if !isAuthenticated {
            tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(res, "login.html", nil)
            return
        }
        showAbout(res, req)
    } else {
        tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(res, "login.html", nil)
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: check all errors. all the time. If you dont know what to do about them, just `log.Println` with a prefix to differentiate an error from this or that part of the app, like `log.Println("about:", err)`

Comment: @mh-cbon I have a problem that `tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(res, "about.html", d)` is not executing.

Comment: i guess this has to do with database.Insertdata("about", content) but you know, not much information about that specifically

Comment: @mh-cbon I updated the code adding the `Insertdata()` function

Comment: @mh-cbon Whenever I insert the data in the about field, it gives the success message two times.

Comment: You shouldn't invoke `ExecuteTemplate` more than **once** per request. In `showAbout` if aboutdata is empty you are invoking `tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(res, "aboutform.html", nil)` and then if inserted is true you are invoking `tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(res, "about.html", d)`... You shouldn't do that.

Comment: @mkopriva What should I do instead?

Comment: @sikandarmeranam it's hard to say what *exactly* you should do because it is unclear what you're trying to do, the code in the question doesn't make much sense, I'm afraid, which makes it difficult for me to provide an exact solution to your problem. I can only tell what you can *not* do: executing a template and expecting that that will trigger a new request-response cycle and allow you to immediately access the new request's data through the old request. i.e. on one line you have `tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(res, "aboutform.html", nil)`...

Comment: @sikandarmeranam ...and on the line right after that you have `content := req.FormValue("content")` where you expect `"content"` to have been submited through the template you've just rendered on the previous line. That's simply not how the HTTP client-server request-response communication happens, at least not in Go. Rendering a template and submitting data through that template are two separate request-response cycles, not one-and-the-same cycle.

Comment: @mkopriva `if inserted == true` is working and it is giving me the success message also. But as you said that I can't use `tmpl.ExecuteTemplate()` more than once in one request. I made a separate function in which I wrote `tmpl.ExecuteTemplate()` and then used `http.Redirect()` to call the `about` but it still didn't work.

Comment: @sikandarmeranam `ExecuteTemplate` writes to the response, the status code in an HTTP response is on the first line so it must be written before the body is written, hence `ExecuteTemplate` will cause the HTTP response status code to be `200` if it wasn't pre-set. An HTTP redirect has a 3xx status code which is what the `http.Redirect` function attempts to write to the response, but you can't write two responses. Calling `ExecuteTemplate` and then `http.Redirect` is even more pointless than calling `ExecuteTemplate` twice.

Comment: @mkopriva The purpose of my code is to open an about page and see whether the data in the database is present or not. `(1)` If it is present then go to `about.html` file to see the data in the browser as I have done this in the else-statement in `showAbout()` function. `(2)` If the data is not present in the database then open a form, fill up, insert that data in the database, show the success message and then go back to `about.html` file to view the data in the browser.

Comment: i suggest you this reading to improve the clarity of your future code. https://betterprogramming.pub/are-early-returns-any-good-eed4b4d03866

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how your about handler may look like. Keep in mind that the example is just an illustration of a generic structure for handling GET and POST request's with a single handler. From what I can tell the code in your question contains a number of other logical errors that you'll still have to resolve.

Notice that the logic of rendering the template and handling data input is split between the GET and POST HTTP methods. Some routers allow for method-based handler registering in which case you could have two separate handlers, one for `showAbout` and another for `createAbout` or something.

The use of `return` statements in this example is unnecessary given how the `if-else` blocks are structured, however, I did include them anyway to explicitly illustrate that, *in general*, after you write to the response once you should *not* have any other response-writing code: no `http.Redirect`, no more `ExecuteTemplate` calls, etc.

```golang
func handleAbout(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method == "GET" {
         if data_is_present {
             if err := t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "about.html", nil); err != nil {
                 fmt.Println(err)
             }
             return
         } else if data_is_NOT_present {
             if err := t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "aboutform.html", nil); err != nil {
                 fmt.Println(err)
             }
             return
         }
    } else if r.Method == "POST" {
        content := r.FormValue("content")
        inserted := database.Insertdata("about", content)
        if inserted == true {
            d := struct{ Aboutdata string }{Aboutdata: content}
            if err := t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "about.html", d); err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
            return
        } else {
            fmt.Println("About is not inserted")
            return
        }
    }
}
```